# How to use regex to replace part of string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How do I search a string in Javascript for all instances of `[SM_g]randomword[SM_h].` and replace them all with `[SM_g]randomword.[SM_h]`.

I'd also like to do this with commas. For example - I need to be able to turn `[SM_g]randomword[SM_h],` into `[SM_g]randomword,[SM_h]`.

Here is my code so far:

```
const periodRegex = /\[SM_g](.*?)\[SM_h](?:[.])/g;
string_afterregex - string_initial.replace(periodRegex, /*I don't know what goes in here*/)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the patterns and then reorder with back reference:

```js
const periodRegex = /(\[SM_g].*?)(\[SM_h])([.,])/g;

var string_initial = '[SM_g]randomword[SM_h].'
var string_afterregex = string_initial.replace(periodRegex, "$1$3$2");
console.log(string_afterregex);

var string_initial = '[SM_g]randomword[SM_h],'
console.log(string_initial.replace(periodRegex, "$1$3$2"))
```

Comment: Your answer did not quite work because it turned `[SM_g]randomword[SM_h].` into `[SM_g]randomword.[SM_h].` instead of `[SM_g]randomword.[SM_h]` However, I figured out that by changing your regex to `/(\[SM_g].*?)(\[SM_h])([.])/g` then I would have the solution. If you want to update your solution, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question very carefully first time. I guess you want to move the trailing `.` or `,` after the `randomword` instead of simply inserting a character.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use multiple regexes to achieve what you want if you benefit from lookaheads:

```js
const re = /\[SM_g](?=(((?:(?!\[SM_h]).)*)\[SM_h])([.,]))\1./g;
const str = '[SM_g]$2$3[SM_h]';

console.log("[SM_g]WORD[SM_h], [SM_g]WORD[SM_h]. [SM_g]WORD[SM_h]".replace(re, str));
```

Breakdown:

- `\[SM_g]` Match `[SM_g]` literally
- `(?=` Start of a positive lookahead

  - `(` Start of capturing group #1

    - `(` Start of CG #2

      - `(?:` Start of NCG #1, tempered dot

        - `(?!\[SM_h])`. Match next character without skipping over a `[SM_h]`
      - `)*` End of NCG #1, repeat as much as possible
    - `)` End of CG #2
    - `\[SM_h]` Match `[SM_h]` literally
  - `)` End of CG #2
  - `(` Start of CG #3

    - `[.,]` Match a comma or a period
  - `)` End of CG #4
- `)` End of positive lookahead
- `\1.` Match what's matched by CG #1 then a character